# Handling data skewness in pyspark rangeBetween

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, window-functions

I am trying to calculate count, mean and average over rolling window using rangeBetween in pyspark. Some of the mid in my data are heavily skewed because of which its taking too long to compute.

I am first grouping the data on epoch level and then using the window function. This reduces the compute time but still its taking longer than expected.

Can someone please suggest optimizing this code or any other approach.

I am using the below code:

```
def get_window_spec(partitioncol, ordercol, start, end):
     
   return Window.partitionBy(partitioncol).orderBy(ordercol).rangeBetween(start, end)`


group_cols = ["mid"]

midstatsdf = filtereddatadf.groupBy(group_cols + ["epochtime"])\
    .agg(count("*").alias("mid_epoch_lvl_cnt"), \
        sum("amount").alias("mid_epoch_lvl_sum"))\
    .withColumn("mid_occur_num_1day", \
        F.sum(col("mid_epoch_lvl_cnt")).over(get_window_spec(group_cols,"epochtime",-24*60*60, 0))) \
    .withColumn("mid_sum_1day", \
        F.sum(col("mid_epoch_lvl_sum")).over(get_window_spec(group_cols,"epochtime",-24*60*60, 0)))\
    .withColumn("mid_avg_1day", \
                col("mid_sum_1day")/col("mid_occur_num_1day"))\
    .drop("mid_epoch_lvl_cnt","mid_epoch_lvl_sum")
```

Comment: So you need at the end this avg per second?

Comment: What's your data volume, number of records and 99% percentile of count by `mid`?